# Python module 'AppKit' has no attribute 'NSEvent'

Tags: python, objective-c, appkit, pyautogui

I was trying to use module 'pyautogui' as follow:

```
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages')

import pyautogui

screenWidth, screenHeight = pyautogui.size()
mouseX, mouseY = pyautogui.position()
```

But it threw an error like this:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/sitepackages/pyautogui/_pyautogui_osx.py", line 296, in _position
    loc = AppKit.NSEvent.mouseLocation()
AttributeError: module 'AppKit' has no attribute 'NSEvent'
```

Comment: This works fine on my El Capitan macOS machine, running PyAutoGUI version 0.9.38. Have you named a file AppKit.py? Your script will be importing that file instead of the real AppKit module. What version of Python are you using to run this code? Why are you appending to sys.path?

Comment: I have named a file AppKit.py in the AppKit directory, but it didn't work.